# Python with flask login system internal server error

Tags: python, mysql, flask

so i practice make a login system with a python and flask. 
and this is the code that I wrote.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, redirect, url_for
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import threading
import MySQLdb.cursors
import re

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'db_pkk'

mysql = MySQL(app)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    msg = ''
    if request.methods == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form:
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM tb_admin WHERE username = %s AND password = %s', (username, password))
    tb_admin = cursor.fetchone()

    if tb_admin:
        session['loggedin'] = True
        session['id'] = tb_admin ['id']
        session['username'] = tb_admin ['username']
        return 'Logged in succesfully'
    else:
        msg = 'Incorret username/password !'

    return render_template('login/login.html', msg = msg)

def runFlaskApp():
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5001, debug=False, threaded=True)

if __name__== "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=runFlaskApp())
    t1.start()
```

I don't know why when I tried it in the browser, an internal server error message came out.

Comment: You can set `debug=True` to get error detail.`request.methods` is wrong

Comment: +1 since this is the first answer that popped up on google when searching for: flask auth_user internal server error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `debug=True` to get error detail.

`request.method` instead of `request.methods`